# Why am I getting a NoSuchMethodError in this code?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab50 {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Student Information");
        TreeSet set = new TreeSet();
        set.add(new Student(87, "Andy"));
        set.add(new Student(99, "Bichel"));
        set.add(new Student(12, "Chuck"));
        set.add(new Student(45, "David"));

        Iterator it = set.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
    }
}

class Student implements Comparable {    
    int sid;
    String name;

    Student(int sid, String name) {
        this.sid = sid;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Student) {
            Student st = (Student) obj;
            return this.sid - st.sid;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return sid + "\t" + name;
    }
}
```

I am getting the error on the first line of adding the element of Andy. Following is the error message on the console :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Student.(ILjava/lang/String;)V
>           at Lab50.main(Lab50.java:6)

Comment: Are you running it against an old version of the `Student` class?

Comment: Aside: don't use raw types: `TreeSet<Student> set= new TreeSet<>();`; `Iterator<Student> it = set.iterator();`; `class Student implements Comparable<Student>`.

Comment: No errors in your code, it prints the follow:
`Student Information
12 Chuck
45 David
87 Andy
99 Bichel`

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but what do you exactly mean by running against old version of Student class? I am a novice.

Comment: @Dhruv you haven't recompiled the `Student` class since you made the changes to add the constructor.

Comment: Your code [is running fine](http://rextester.com/YLVYG21381), and the suggestion by @AndyTurner is a good place to start.

Comment: I just changed the classname Student to something else and it ran successfully. Thanks Andy. Can someone explain what could have been wrong?

Comment: I executed the program using eclipse. So since eclipse compiles automatically, how am I being asked to compile again? What am I missing?

Comment: @Dhruv, by chance, did you make any modifications to the Student class outside of Eclipse, before the error occurred? Eclipse does not automatically pickup changes made outside of it - this would require you to refresh the instance (which causes a re-compile).

Comment: I don't think I did, but I can recompile in eclipse with the help of refresh? That's new for me munyul. Thanks for that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodException.html) for that exception is pretty clear:

> Thrown when a particular method cannot be found.

This means: at **runtime**, when your JVM executes a class; the JVM wants to invoke a certain method. It looks into the corresponding class - and it doesn't find a method with that name/signature in that class. In your case, the **compiled** Student.class simply does *not* contain a constructor that fits the intended usage.

That happens when you have A.java and B.java; and A is calling something in B. Then you change B.java, and re-compile it; but you forgot to recompile A.java.

In other words: you ran into a inconsistency where some A class is trying to use a method of some B class that B.class actually does not contain.

The *real* answer here: make sure that your compiled output is **always** consistent. Meaning: recompile *everything* together.

In the "real" world, such things are handled by build systems for example. In other words: if you want to avoid such issues, either use an IDE that keeps track of all your classes in your project and tells you about such problems when you *insert* them into your code; or learn how to use a build system such as ant, maven, gradle, ... that allows to "clean" up your build output, or that automatically re-compiles all artifacts that need re-compiling.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. But the only question I have is, since Eclipse compiles automatically, why do I have to recompile manually? What am I missing?

Comment: How are you building and running your application?  Perhaps this is not as automatic as you think.

Comment: Uhmm.. when I am writing the code in eclipse, I do not have to provide a separate command for compilation whereas in case I am compiling with the help of command prompt, I have to provide the command : javac classname.java ?

Comment: @Dhruv Turn to the top menu "Project" and check if "Build automatically" has a check mark next to it. If not, check that. If it has; try to clean/build all. Maybe you have to exit Eclipse. You are correct; when you are running with normal default settings, such problems should not occur.

Comment: `That happens when you have A.java and B.java; and A is calling something in B. Then you change B.java, and re-compile it; but you forgot to recompile A.java.`    Or something more sneaky I've seen is that you compile with version X of a library but deploy and run with version Y of a library.  This is quite possible with projects using ivy/maven/gradle whose dependencies have common transitive dependencies but with different versions.

Comment: @GhostCat  I have tried everything. Build automatically had a check mark next to it by default and even after cleaning and running it again, it still keeps giving the same error. I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Is your project all your own source code? Or do you stuff put in jar files? Do you have one project or multiple?

Comment: In any case: you want to show us your student class. And: are you sure you have exactly one class named Student?